# eazyBI Issue status built from sub-task status

Tags: mdx

I have Issues which have sub-tasks. If at least one of the sub-task is CLOSED, I want to consider that the Parent issue is CLOSED. And if not, then if there is at least one of the sub-task is SOLVED, I want to consider that the Parent issue is SOLVED. In case of any other status of the sub-tasks, the Parent issue is in state "other" "which is not a real state, juste to agregate other states.

In other words, how to display Issues by status that is a synthesis of status of the sub-taks ?
I do not know where to start with